# VS 2013 Bootstrap files missing when creating a new web application

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap

With VS 2013 (Update 2) 
I add a new web application - Templates | Visual Basic | Web | Visual Studio 2012 | ASP.NET Web Forms Application..

Once saved and launched default.aspx displays 'To learn more about ASP.NET visit....' not the 'ASP.NET is a free web framework...' that all the tutorial screenshots display. There is no bootstrap.css file created and adding one from bootswatch and adding it to bundle.config just causes the markup to look very odd and unreadable.

Is there something I have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that bootstrap is not installed by default, and it took a bit of head scratching to figure it out.

Right click the solution and open 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solution'

From the left hand menu select 'Online' and nuget.org - from the centre window select Bootstrap and click install.

It should now show in 'Installed packages'

Hope this makes life a little easier for someone :-)

UPDATE

I have also discovered that if you set up the project as - Templates | Visual Basic | Web | 
ASP.NET Web Application and then select Web Forms the bootstrap files are installed.

As I start a new project very rarely it is very easy to miss that nuance